# Replace an existing content in a table (without memory-leaks) in C

Tags: arrays, c, linux, memory-leaks

Here is my problem.

I would like to change two of the contents of an array of words (the array is made up of numbers only) using the addresses (void myfunction(&tabs[0], &tabs[1])) but I have memory errors.

In my array I have for example: tabs[0] = "12" and tabs[1] = "2" and I would like to replace them by 012 and 002. Once I have these values, I free tabs[0] and tabs[1] and strdup the two new values back into tabs[0] and tabs[1] but I get errors. I don't see how to do this.

Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
char *infinyAdd(char *number1, char *number2)
{
    char result[4080] = {0};

    findSizeStr(&number1, &number2);
    fprintf(stdout, "Transform: %s - %s\n", number1, number2);

    // fprintf(stdout, "Number 01: %s - Number 02: %s\n", number1, number2);
    // sprintf(result, "%d", atoi(number1) + atoi(number2));
    return (strdup("42")); // Don't worry about that
}
```

```
void setZeroStr(char *toSet, char *oneZero, size_t lenght, bool state)
{
    char num1[4080] = {0};
    char num2[4080] = {0};

    (state == true) ? sprintf(num1, "0%s", toSet), sprintf(num2, "0%s", oneZero) : \
        sprintf(num1, "%s%s", memset(num1, '0', lenght), toSet), sprintf(num2, "0%s", oneZero);

    free(toSet); // Here is the problem
    free(oneZero); // Here is the problem
    toSet = strdup(num1);
    oneZero = strdup(num2);
}

void findSizeStr(char **number01, char **number02)
{
    switch (sizeStr((*number01), (*number02))) {
        case LONG: setZeroStr((*number02), (*number01), strlen((*number01)), false);
        break;
        case SHORT: setZeroStr((*number01), (*number02), strlen((*number02)), false);
        break;
        case EQUAL: setZeroStr((*number02), (*number01), 0, true);
        break;
        default: fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error: String Invalid\n"); break;
    }
}
```

Here is the leaks:

```
Your operation: 10 + 2
Your operand: +
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x483DB86: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:459)
==7370==    by 0x48DB74D: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c620 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x483DB94: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:459)
==7370==    by 0x48DB74D: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c621 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x48F0D24: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48D9C16: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c621 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x4842130: mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1536)
==7370==    by 0x48F0C41: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48D9C16: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c620 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
Transform: 10 - 2
Resultat: 42
==7370== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x401C45: freeTabs (array.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x401401: doOperand (main.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c620 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== 
==7370== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7370==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==7370==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 5,306 bytes allocated
==7370== 
==7370== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401A06: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:25)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401A1C: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:26)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7370==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==7370==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7370==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7370==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7370==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7370== 
==7370== ERROR SUMMARY: 15 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==7370== 
==7370== 2 errors in context 1 of 7:
==7370== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x401C45: freeTabs (array.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x401401: doOperand (main.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c620 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== 
==7370== 2 errors in context 2 of 7:
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x483DB86: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:459)
==7370==    by 0x48DB74D: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c620 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== 
==7370== 3 errors in context 3 of 7:
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x4842130: mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1536)
==7370==    by 0x48F0C41: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48D9C16: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c620 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== 
==7370== 3 errors in context 4 of 7:
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x48F0D24: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48D9C16: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c621 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== 
==7370== 3 errors in context 5 of 7:
==7370== Invalid read of size 1
==7370==    at 0x483DB94: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:459)
==7370==    by 0x48DB74D: __vfprintf_internal (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x48C6109: fprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401592: infinyAdd (addition.c:20)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Address 0x4a3c621 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==7370==    at 0x483B9F5: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:538)
==7370==    by 0x4019F7: setZeroStr (modifyString.c:24)
==7370==    by 0x401A98: findSizeStr (modifyString.c:32)
==7370==    by 0x40156B: infinyAdd (addition.c:19)
==7370==    by 0x40138E: doOperand (main.c:35)
==7370==    by 0x4014C0: coreSystem (main.c:59)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370==  Block was alloc'd at
==7370==    at 0x483A809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==7370==    by 0x48FE0AE: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.31.so)
==7370==    by 0x401D8E: wordsArray (array.c:42)
==7370==    by 0x4014A9: coreSystem (main.c:58)
==7370==    by 0x401505: main (main.c:67)
==7370== 
==7370== ERROR SUMMARY: 15 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You mention words which would basically mean integers of some size but you seem to deal with strings. Please show how you call your function. Edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `toSet = strdup(num1);` This will only assign to the local copy of the argument inside that function. It will not be visible outside of that function. Also you write that you call your function with passing the address of array elements. You cannot pass addresses within an array to `free` as they cannot be allocated via `malloc`. Only the whole array could be freed if it was allocated via `malloc`

Comment: `sprintf(num1, "%s%s", memset(num1, '0', lenght), toSet)` is undefined behavior, source and destination of `sprintf` may not overlap.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I will try another manner.

Answer (score 0):

use the free() function before quitting your program, I think the leaks come from your maloc of number1 & number2 variables.

Try to fix all your valgrind issues that will also surely help you to have a better code

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but the strange trenery operation gives me the willies...

See what you can make of this:

```
int main() {
    char *leadFill = "000000000000"; // As many as needed...
    char *str = "QuickBrownFoxes";
    printf( "%.*s%s\n", 10, leadFill, str );
    printf( "%.*s%s\n", 5, leadFill, str );
    printf( "%.*s%s\n", 0, leadFill, str );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0000000000QuickBrownFoxes
00000QuickBrownFoxes
QuickBrownFoxes
```